# PHP Cannot delete this cookie if my life depended on it

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am creating a simple Logout script and my cookie (`"is_logged_in"`), for some reason, cannot be deleted, despite all of my efforts.
I have tried all of the following (+ lots more):
`setcookie("is_logged_in");`
`setcookie("is_logged_in","");`
`setcookie("is_logged_in","",time()-3600);`
`setcookie("is_logged_in","",time()-3600,"\");`
`setcookie("is_logged_in",FALSE); # or NULL, 0, etc.`
`unset($_COOKIE["is_logged_in"]);`

Here is my PHP code (and yes there is a `session_start()` but it just isn't included in this excerpt).

```
<?php
    require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/taxi/support/required_classes.php";
    ob_start();
    class Logout {
        final public function __construct(){
            $_SESSION = array();
            if(isset($_COOKIE["is_logged_in"])) {
                setcookie("is_logged_in","",time()-3600,"/");
            } // end if
            session_destroy();
            header("location: ../pages/index.php");
        } // end __construct
    } // end class Logout
    $_logout = new Logout();
    ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: So the sessions does not get destroyed, or the user is still logged in? If the last, check the cache headers

Comment: The cookie just will not be un-set. If I `var_dump` it, then it always returns `string(1) "1"`, both before and after the above code is used.